# templated function doesn't accept primitive types?

Tags: c++, templates

this code does not compile but i don't why, also the `typeid()` function can take `int` as input parameter so the problem must be related to the template mechanism but i don't get the rationale behind this fail.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template<typename T> void func(T)
{
  std::cout << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  func(int);  
  return(0);
}
```

What is wrong with this template/code ?

Comment: `int` is not an `int`. `int` is a type (not a value). `0` is an `int`.

Comment: BTW, **don't** use `std::endl`. If you really mean to flush the output, use `std::flush`.

Comment: @DietmarKühl because it slows down the terminal output or for other reasons ?

Comment: Yes. Unnecessary use of `std::endl` causes performance problems. People using it as a default will introduce problems which may involve a lot if changes to solve them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass an instance of type `int`, not the type itself:

```
func(int());
        ^^ note the parentheses
```

If you don't want to pass an instance around, you could change your code like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

template<typename T> void func()
{
  std::cout << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
  func<int>();
  return(0);
}
```

Comment: how to pass a type and not an instance ? templates can only abstract instances ?

Answer (score 2):

You have to pass some "instance" of type `int` ... not just type itself...

```
func(int(123));
```

will be ok

Comment: The cast isn't needed. `123` has type `int`.

Comment: Just to demonstrate constructor-like form of "instantiation" of int type :)

Comment: it works but it will create an useless object of type int adding an unwanted overhead to the program :! better use `func<int>()` in my case. thanks for the reply anyway.

Comment: FYI, `int()` would create a _default initialized_ `int`... guess the value :)

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with the trmplate code but

```
func(int);
```

isn't valid. You probably meant

```
func(int());
```

Comment: yes but int() is a constructor meaning that I always have to call an instance creating an object of type int on the fly. What about passing just the type keyword ?

Comment: If you don't want to create an object your function shouldn't take an argument. If it doesn't take an argument the template type can't be deduced and you'd call the function like this: `func<int>()`.

Comment: how this signature is called ? what kind of call is `func<int>()` ?

Comment: It's a function call, calling a function template with an explicitly specified template argument. `func` is a function template, `func<int>` is an instantiation of a function template.

Comment: ok, I was thinking about a particular explicit template call with a special name; thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to explicitly instantiate and call your function with `T` set to `int`, you have to pass that `int` as a *template* argument: `foo<int>`.

This does not excuse you from supplying the "ordinary" argument, since you declared your function with one "ordinary" parameter of type `T`.

So, valid calls to `foo` with explicitly specified template argument might look as follows

```
foo<int>(0);
foo<int>(true);
foo<int>('a');
```

(the purpose of explicit specification of template argument is to override the template argument deduction mechanism).

If your intent was to keep that "ordinary" parameter as a fictive one (since you didn't even bother to give it a name), you can supply it with a default argument

```
template<typename T> void func(T = T())
{
  std::cout << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
}
```

in which case your function will become callable as

```
foo<int>();
```

Or you can get rid of the ordinary parameter entirely (since you are not using it inside the function anyway)

```
template<typename T> void func()
{
  std::cout << typeid(T).name() << std::endl;
}
```

albeit this will force you to always specify the template argument explicitly.

If you had something else in mind, you have to explain what it is.

Comment: `foo<int>();` is equivalent to `foo<int>(0);` ?

Comment: No. `foo<int>()` assumes that `foo()` can be called without arguments.

Comment: @user1849534: Huh? For the OP's declaration of `foo`, `foo<int>()` is **NOT** equivalent to `foo<int>(0)`. `foo<int>()` is simply invalid. The function argument is required and cannot be omitted.

Comment: `func<int>()` works on g++-4.7 with no problems ... it's a valid call apparently

Comment: @user1849534: Just because something "works" in g++ does not mean it is valid. Gcc compilers are not exactly known as pillars of standard compliance (at least with their default settings). Although it find it hard to believe that this compiles in g++. This sort of "extension" would break a lot of code. Are you sure your definition of `foo` is the same as in the OP's code?

Comment: it's 1:1 , also i have compiled this code with `g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra` and nothing shows up

Comment: @user1849534" You need to re-check the code you are compiling. You must have inadvertently supplied a default argument for your parameter. With your *original* code, the `foo<int>()` call does not compile in any version of g++.

Comment: @user1849534: But you removed the unnamed parameter declaration from your function! Again, my answer and my comments apply to the *original* code supplied in the original question. The code you ran in ideone is significantly different. Your original code will not allow `foo<int>()` call. Your new code will not allow `foo<int>(0)` call. So, there no "equivalence" of any kind here.

Comment: you just said "foo<int>() is simply invalid", this is my point, i can use foo like that, i don't get what you are saying with this comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13884566/templated-function-doesnt-accept-primitive-types/13884662#comment19125858_13884662

Comment: Whether it is valid or not depends on how `foo` is declared. In my comment I meant that `foo<int>()` is simply invalid *given your original declaration of `foo`*. Now, when you said that "`foo<int>()` is equivalent to `foo<int>(0)`" what specific declaration of `foo` were you talking about?